# QGIS: How to store the GPS coordinates in the attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, gps, coordinates, elevation

I got vector points on a map. I already have the elevation information in the table for each vector point and the point-id. Now I want to get the GPS coordinates for each point stored in this attribute table. How can I do that?

Overall my aim is to get to know the gradient on this line which I divided into those points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your layer already is in EPSG:4326 use the following expressions:

- For field y/lat use: `$y`
- For field x/lon use: `$x`

If your layer is in another projection use:

For field y/lat:

```
y(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'),
       'EPSG:4326'))
```

For field x/lon:

```
x(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'),
   'EPSG:4326'))
```

Create the fields with fieldcalculator and make sure to set field type to `Decimal number (real)` and `set its precision`.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

`vector -> geometry tools -> add geometry attributes` adds columns with you coordinates in the layers CRS to its attribute table.