# Merging attributes of selected features tool not working in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, merge

I want to combine some columns between 2 data attribute tables.

The question, which I asked a while ago:
[Copying features from one attribute table to another using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341667/copying-features-from-one-attribute-table-to-another-using-qgis)
leads to quote long way.

Recently I "discovered" another tool, which might be far quicker. The tool is the "Merge attributes of selected features" located in the advanced toolbar.

I found some answer, which could be helpful: [Copy attributes from one feature to empty row of another feature in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357189/copy-attributes-from-one-feature-to-empty-row-of-another-feature-in-qgis-3),
but it doesn't work in my case really.

I want to copy the XY coordinates from one attribute table to another.

[image]

and I was following the instructions from the thread above.

Unfortunately in my case, nothing happens. When I click OK my data attribute table remains still empty.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you made sure, both columns have the same field type? Couldn't you use `join attributes by field`?

Comment: yes I am sure. Firstly I created the data attribute table, and next I did the centroid option from Vector section in order to gain the coordinates for my polygons. The centroid option generated the separate layer for me with the same data attribute layer. Next I could use the coordinates calculation for points, which I want now to transfer into another data attribute table

Comment: How do these attribute tables differ, other than one has the coordinates, and the other doesn't?

Comment: Yes indeed. One attribute table has X(East) and Y(North) filled in, whereas other don't. I want to copy the data from one to another.

Comment: And the second table is the one which belongs to the "original" polygons?

Comment: yes, the empty one

Comment: Then I strongly suggest you make your life easier by using `x(centroid($geometry))` respectively `y(centroid($geometry))` on the polygon layer and forget about creating centroids and rejoining the attributes.

Comment: You are fantastic! It can be. However how it could work for Latitude and longitude?
In the question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312359/qgis-how-to-store-the-gps-coordinates-in-the-attribute-table
there is an expression:
x(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'),
   'EPSG:4326'))
shall I use then: x(centroid(transform($geometry...)?

Comment: Depends on which CRS your layer is in, and which CRS the coordinates should be in. If both are the same, you don't need to use `transform`.

Comment: Yes indeed mate! The expression: y(centroid(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'),
       'EPSG:4326'))) gives a latitude result! Many thanks for today's help!

Comment: However the question itself still remains open as an alternative way ;)

Comment: Keep in mind the representative point https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373547/creating-centroid-inside-of-polygon

Comment: Ok thanks, but I still need to know, why my "Merging attributes oof selected features" tool is not working

Comment: Can you share your data or at least an extract of it with us?